# recover disconnected mapped drive

Tags: networking, mapped-drive

Is there anyway to recover a mapped drive that was disconnected without knowing the server address or name? I do not want to browse through over 85 server ips to find the correct one.

Comment: I think this should be asked at http://superuser.com/?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From googling "windows history of mapped drives" i came upon [this](http://www.r1-forum.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-52143.html).

> Doing a quick search of my reg, I found the following keys contain drive map history:
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Map Network Drive MRU
>   HKEY_USERS\ \Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Map Network Drive MRU

I've just checked my own registry and it seems to work.

Lots of others will be findable by searching for 'MRU' apparently.

Comment: How do you mean? The tag "Map Network Drive MRU" will then have a key in it when you click on it. It'll say something like "\\server\host"

Comment: I have nothing set for the MRU  default (value not set)

Comment: 'MRU' isn't a key itself... you get keys named "something MRU", like "Map Network Drive MRU" in different locations. See the two examples in my post.

Comment: thanks for the response, was able to identify server by going through first 25

Answer (score 2):

My old mount point didn't appear in the registry when I searched for "MRU" on my Windows 7 laptop. I'm guessing I re-logged in too often after losing the mount point, and thus the history was lost.

But I was able to find my old mount path listed under **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2** . You might find your old mount listed as one of the keys under the above key. Just replace any hash marks (#) with back slashes (\).

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion that I think a lot of people overlooked. It took me a while to find it.  Since it's a server I was having issues with, I looked at users, ctl - alt -del. Then I noticed another login under users. Same user name, logged off, but still there. I then logged them off again, using the option, logoff, suddenly my mapped drives are fine. Shows amount of storage, used, etc. So looks like this solved my issue with losing mapped drives. Hope this helps others still scratching there heads.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `wmic` command to find out the map drives history:

```
wmic path win32_mappedlogicaldisk get DeviceID, ProviderName
```